# How to find the circumcircle radius from this following regular hexagon?

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

Given a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$. We draw diagonals $AC$ and $CE$.

Then, we choose two points in the hexagon's diagonals(AC and CE), call that $M$ and $N$, such that:
$\frac{AM}{AC} =\frac{CN}{CE}$.

If $B, M$ and $N$ are collinear, how to find the circumradius of this hexagon?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting your questions? As @MvG points out, a regular hexagon's circumradius has nothing to do with $M$ and $N$. Your other recent geometry questions are also somewhat flawed. I had thought this might be due to a language issue ---and there's nothing wrong with that--- but this hexagon problem makes me wonder if there's more to it.

Comment: By the way, since $AC=CE$, the proportionality condition says simply that $AM=CN$. Calling the common distance $r$, we can draw circles of radius $r$ about $A$ and $C$. For a given line $\ell$ through $B$, then, $M$ is one of the pts where $\ell$ meets $\bigcirc A$, and $N$ is one of the pts where $\ell$ meets $\bigcirc C$. This can happen in lots of ways. Based on previous questions, I wonder if the description intends (for large-enough $r$) that $M$ and $N$ are the two pts where $\bigcirc A$ and $\bigcirc C$ meet. (Note that the line joining these pts necessarily contains $B$ (and $E$).)

Comment: @Blue, I got it from geometry challenge book. But, the writer didn't insert the answer. So, I think this is good for us to become a problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you indicate the name of that book, and the page where this problem was stated? It would be interesting to know this. Even if the book isn't in English.

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't know the name of the book. I got it from my friend, and I guess that this problem was taken from geometry challenge book. @MvG, if you want, I will insert the original question. Thanks

Comment: @akusaja: Yes, please show the original question.

Comment: Here the original question: Diagonals AC and CE of regular hexagon ABCDEF are divided by inner points M and N respectively, such that AM/AC= CN/CE. Determine r, if B,M,N are collinear? Thanks

Comment: @akusaja: Ah ... The fact that $M$ and $N$ are on the diagonals (and not simply "random points inside the hexagon") makes a BIG difference! (Be sure to give the original questions from now on. :) The figure is now uniquely determined. It's still odd to have a proportionality statement that reduces to $AM=CN$, but ok. If I can trust my figure, it appears that the $\bigcirc A$ and $\bigcirc C$ from my previous comment must pass through $B$ itself, which means that the side of the hexagon (and therefore, the radius of the circumcircle) is equal to the common distance $AM=CN$. Now to prove it!

Comment: Thanks, now I realized that inner points in the hexagon is not same with random points. So, I'll try to use your clue to finish this proof. Thanks for your clue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for your [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/724389/2) I don't see what $M$ and $N$ have to do with anything. Here is the described situation, or as close as I could get with only a bit of manual tweaking, no script:

[image: Almost the desired configuration]

$M$ and $N$ can be pretty much anywhere, and the circumcircle radius of this hexagon is the same as for any other regular hexagon: it's equal to the edge length. Could the rest be a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)?